Cannot publish AvaloniaUI app for Android - error NETSDK1084 There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier
I try to publish AvaloniaUI app for Android. I create the "Folder" publish profile with the following settings:

Then I click on Publish.
The following error appears:
Error XA1030: The 'RunAOTCompilation' MSBuild property is only supported when trimming is enabled. Edit the project file in a text editor to set 'PublishTrimmed' to 'true' for this build configuration.

I add the following line into the .csproj file:
        <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>

and click on Publish again. The following error appears:
error NETSDK1098: Applications published to a single-file are required to use the application host. You must either set PublishSingleFile to false or set UseAppHost to true.

Now I add the following line to .csproj:
        <UseAppHost>true</UseAppHost>

and click on Publish again but the error doesn't hide. I move the following lines:
        <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
        <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
        <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
        <UseAppHost>true</UseAppHost>


into FolderProfile.pubxml and click on Publish again. The following error appears:

Error NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm64'.

What to do next? How to add that "application host"? I have spent several hours but didn't solve this problem.
The answer described here does not help.
EDIT: for @jdweng: here is my runtimeconfig.json file.


The profile setting image you posted and a trim checkbox. Do a google search for : core publish runtime library

@jdweng: I have done search, nothing helpful. At the last state, "trim checkbox" is enabled.

Did you check the runtime.json file?

@jdweng: I do not know what means "runtime.json", there is no such file in my project. If you meant runtimeconfig.json, I have added it to the question body.

Something is wrong between the csproj file and the json file.  Not sure what is the issue.  Read following carefully : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/#runtimeconfigjson
